# Integration of a second order nonlinear ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to verify that the solution to

$(1-f)\big(\frac{dy}{dt}\big)^2+\big(\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}+2\big)y=0$

is

$t=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3-2f}\int_y^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{-x+x^{2(f-1)}}}dx$

where, $f$ is a constant. I can verify it by substituting the solution back into the equation, but I would like to arrive at the solution from the equation directly.

Can anyone show me the way the do that?

Comment: What is $f$, a constant?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1-f)\big(\frac{dy}{dt}\big)^2+\big(\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}+2\big)y=0$$
Let $\frac{dy}{dt}=F(y) \quad\to\quad \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = \frac{dF}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dF}{dy}F$
$$(1-f)F^2+\big(\frac{dF}{dy}F+2\big)y=0$$
$F^2=u(y) \quad\to\quad (1-f)u+\big(\frac{1}{2}\frac{du}{dy}+2\big)y=0$
$$\frac{du}{dy}+2(1-f)\frac{u}{y} =-4$$
This is a first order linear ODE easy to solve  :
$$u=\frac{4}{2f-3}y+c_1\:y^{2(f-1)}$$
$$F=\pm \sqrt{\frac{4}{2f-3}y+c_1\:y^{2(f-1)}}=\frac{dy}{dt}$$
$dt=\pm\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{2f-3}y+c_1\:y^{2(f-1)}}}$
$$t=\pm\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{2f-3}y+c_1\:y^{2(f-1)}}} =  \pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3-2f}\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{-y+c_2\:y^{2(f-1)}}}$$

The form : $\quad t=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3-2f}\int_y^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{-x+x^{2(f-1)}}}dx\quad $ probably comes from the preceeding one according to some conditions which are missing in the wording of the question. I guess that one of the missing conditions is $y(0)=1$. Probably another missing condition allows to determine $c_2=1$.